# Varnish.4.x not caching range requests

Tags: caching, cloud, reverse-proxy, varnish

We are trying to get Varnish to cache range requests. We are using Varnish 4.0.

We the following configurations

vcl 4.0;

```
import std;

# Default backend definition. Set this to point to your content server.
backend default {
    .host = "194.142.x.x";
    .port = "8008";
}

sub vcl_recv {

if (req.url ~ "(?i)\.(png|avi|mkv|mp4)(\?[a-z0-9]+)?$") {
    unset req.http.Cookie;
  }
    # Happens before we check if we have this in cache already.
    #
    # Typically you clean up the request here, removing cookies you don't need,
    # rewriting the request, etc.

  set req.http.host = regsub(req.http.host, "v\.","\rms\.");

  std.log("REWRITED TO"+req.http.host+"  "+req.url);



}

sub vcl_backend_response {
    # Happens after we have read the response headers from the backend.
    #
    # Here you clean the response headers, removing silly Set-Cookie headers
    # and other mistakes your backend does.
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    # Happens when we have all the pieces we need, and are about to send the
    # response to the client.
    #
                                                               vcl 4.0;

import std;

# Default backend definition. Set this to point to your content server.
backend default {
    .host = "194.142.x.x";
    .port = "8008";
}

sub vcl_recv {

if (req.url ~ "(?i)\.(png|avi|mkv|mp4)(\?[a-z0-9]+)?$") {
    unset req.http.Cookie;
  }
    # Happens before we check if we have this in cache already.
    #
    # Typically you clean up the request here, removing cookies you don't need,
    # rewriting the request, etc.

  set req.http.host = regsub(req.http.host, "v\.","\rms\.");

  std.log("REWRITED TO"+req.http.host+"  "+req.url);



}

sub vcl_backend_response {
    # Happens after we have read the response headers from the backend.
    #
    # Here you clean the response headers, removing silly Set-Cookie headers
    # and other mistakes your backend does.
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    # Happens when we have all the pieces we need, and are about to send the
    # response to the client.
    #
```

how ever range requests are taking too long to be served so we feel its not being cached as the original server is hit.

Comment: There is not enough information here. A varnishlog entry of such a slow request is necessary. In general, unless the request is piped/passed, Varnish will ask for a normal fetch of the object from the backend and start serving the client whenever the byte range asked for appears.

Answer (score 1):

Can you solve this...?

I'm pretty sure the block config:

```
if (req.url ~ "(?i)\.(png|avi|mkv|mp4)(\?[a-z0-9]+)?$") {
    unset req.http.Cookie;
  }
    # Happens before we check if we have this in cache already.
    #
    # Typically you clean up the request here, removing cookies you don't need,
    # rewriting the request, etc.

  set req.http.host = regsub(req.http.host, "v\.","\rms\.");
  std.log("REWRITED TO"+req.http.host+"  "+req.url);
```

Are in wrong position, needs to be in vcl_backend_response not in vcl_recv

Answer (score 1):

[Caching partial objects with varnish 4.0](https://info.varnish-software.com/blog/caching-partial-objects-varnish)

```
sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.http.Range ~ "bytes=") {
        set req.http.x-range = req.http.Range;
    }
}

sub vcl_hash {
    if (req.http.x-range ~ "bytes=") {
            hash_data(req.http.x-range);
            unset req.http.Range;
    }
}

sub vcl_backend_fetch {
    if (bereq.http.x-range) {
        set bereq.http.Range = bereq.http.x-range;
    }
}

sub vcl_backend_response {
    if (bereq.http.x-range ~ "bytes=" && beresp.status == 206) {
        set beresp.ttl = 10m;
        set beresp.http.CR = beresp.http.content-range;
    }
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    if (resp.http.CR) {
        set resp.http.Content-Range = resp.http.CR;
        unset resp.http.CR;
    }
}
```

Comment: This works and fixes "416" error from LinkedIn Inspector/Article sharing. Thanks a lot!